# No files found in cypress test runner

Tags: javascript, automation, frameworks, cypress, build-automation

This weird thing happen where I got a ' No files found in cypress test runner' error message all of a sudden.
[image]

However the files are in the folder, I have moved it to a new folder and tried running it but I still got the error message. Please any thoughts or idea as to why this happened?
[image]

I also tried running it in headless mode but I got the same error message.
[image]

Thank you.
@Nanker Phelge please any thoughts as how to fix this issue. Thanks

Comment: What is the config in `cypress.json`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default, if you have not configured anything different,  Cypress looks in all subfolders of the integration folder.

Please see [Configuration](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/configuration.html#Folders-Files)

**Folders / Files**

| Option | Default |
| --- | --- |
| testFiles | `**/*.*` |

where `**` is part of a glob pattern that means 'look in all the sub folders - for all file types'.

If you have something else configured, that might be causing it, but if there is no entry then `cypress.json` is not the cause.

Else, if you have `*.spec.js` or `*/*.js` these will exclude your files (because there's no `.spec.js` extension and a single `*` will exclude subfolders.

Speaking of excluding, if there is an `ignoreTestFiles` configuration entry (in `cypress.json`), that may be causing the problem.

---

I would also like to point out the `PageObjects` folder may be considered as tests and cause you more errors.

A common pattern is to name all files that have tests with the `.spec.js` extension e.g `GTProject1.spec.js`.

In the `cypress.json` file, set

```
testFiles: "**/*.spec.js"
```

which means look in the `/cypress/integration` folder and ***any sub-folders*** for files with the extension `.spec.js`. It will ignore you PageObject files which just have the `.js` extension.

Then you can rearrange the folders later and still see all the tests.

Comment: If `testFiles`is are not declared in `cypress.json` then as per the current structure, the Page Objects folder will also be executed.

Comment: But yes you were right about the wordings, cypress does check for all subfolders inside the integration folder, I have removed that and updated my answer.

Comment: @ Nanker Phelge Thanks again. The issue was with the testFiles in the cypress.json. Once I updated it to **/*.* it worked.

Comment: Thank you man :D in my project suddenly i lost all tests, but that was the case, some one changed conf in cypress.js

Answer (score 0):

You can execute tests like this -

```
npx cypress run --spec=cypress/integration/GTProjects/*
```

Or, you can add all your tests as an array under `testFiles` in your `cypress.json` file, and in that case you can directly use `npx cypress run`.

```
"testFiles": [
  "GTProjects/GTProject1.js",
  "GTProjects/GTProject2.js",
  "GTProjects/GTProject3.js",
  "GTProjects/GTProject4.js",
  "GTProjects/GTProject5.js",
  "GTProjects/GTProject6.js",
  "GTProjects/GTProject7.js",
  "GTProjects/GTProject8.js",
  "GTProjects/GTProject9.js"
]
```

Or, You can provide `integrationFolder` path in your `cypress.json` and in that case, also you can execute the tests using `npx cypress run`

```
"integrationFolder": "cypress/integration/GTProjects"
```